# How to set angularjs-slider dirty when the upper or lower value is changed?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularjs range slider (rz-slider) in a form. When the user changes the default values of the slider, I want to set it to dirty and show the new values on a different page. If the user doesn't touch the slider then I don't need to show anything. I tried to add 'name' inside the slider tag but getting errors like '$dirty is undefined'. Here's my code:

```
<div ng-form="budgets">
 <div ng-repeat="budget in totals track by $index"
  <rzslider rz-slider-model="budget.lowerLimit" rz-slider-high="budget.upperLimit" rz-slider-options="sliderRange.options" name="updateSLider{{$index}}></rzslider>
 </div>
</div>

controller:
$scope.sliderRange = {
    options: {
        floor: -100,
        ceil: 100,
        draggableRange: true
    }
};

if ($scope.budgets["updateSLider" + index].$dirty) {
// ...will add the code here to show the new value
```